# How to set expand and collapse in same place using MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

[image]

Description:

The above image will give some details. In my table I want to expand and collapse in same place. If we use MVC we edit the code in INDEX code page. Where we write code in index page how I set both icons `+` `-` in the same place?

Comment: Thanks Marc.. Kindly Help Me For Above Question

Comment: no one can answer this question. kindly help me plzzz